# Replacing a HTML div InnerText tag using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HTML Agility Pack to manipulate and edit a HTML document. I want to change the text in the field such as this:

```
<div id="Div1"><b>Some text here.</b><br></div>
```

I am looking to update the text within this div to be:

```
<div id="Div1"><b>Some other text.</b><br></div>
```

I've tried doing this using the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working because the InnerText property is readonly.

```
HtmlTextNode hNode = null;
hNode = hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='Div1']") as HtmlTextNode;
hNode.InnerText = "Some other text.";
hDoc.Save("C:\FileName.html");
```

What am I doing wrong here? As mentioned above, the InnerText is a read only field, although it's written in the documentation that it "gets or sets". Is there an alternate method through which this can be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression is used here: `//div[@id='Div1']` selects the `div`, which is not a `HtmlTextNode`, so the `hNode` variable holds `null` in your example.

The `InnerText` property is realy read-only, but `HtmlTextNode` has property `Text` which could be used to set the necessary value. But before this you should get that text node. This could be easily done with this expression: `//div[@id='Div1']//b//text()`:

```
hNode = hDoc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='Div1']//b//text()") as HtmlTextNode;
hNode.Text = "Some other text.";
```