# Unable to set InnerText using Html-Agility-Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

Given an HTML document, I want to identify all the numbers in the document and add custom tags around the numbers.
Right now, i use the following:

```
HtmlNodeCollection bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body");
MatchCollection numbersColl = Regex.Matches(htmlNode.InnerText, <some regex>);
```

Once I get the numbersColl, I can traverse through each Match and get the index. 
However, I can't change the InnerText since it is read-only. 
What I need is that if match.Value = 100 and match.Index=25, I want to replace that 25 with 
`<span isIdentified='true'> 25 </span>`

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Currently, since I am not able to modify the inner text, I have to modify the InnerHtml but some element might have 25 in it's innerHtml. That should not be touched. But how do I identify whether the number is within
an html tag i.e. < table border='1' > has 1 in the tag.

Comment: ... within what? It's very hard to follow your requirements here :) If performance isn't an issue you could generate a new HtmlDocument with the fixed strings.

Comment: Clarification provided. Hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I did to work around the read-only property limitation of the *InnerText* property of a **Text** node, just select the **Parent** node of the Text node and note the index of the Text node in the child node collections of the Parent node. Then just do a `ReplaceChild(...)`.

```
       private void WriteText(HtmlNode node, string text)
        {
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                node.ReplaceChild(htmlDocument.CreateTextNode(text), node.ChildNodes.First());
            }
            else
            {
                node.AppendChild(htmlDocument.CreateTextNode(text));
            }
        }
```

In your case I believe you need to create a new Element node that wraps the text into an HtmlElement and then just use it as a replacement of the Text node.

Or even better, see if you can do something like the answer posted here:
[Replacing a HTML div InnerText tag using HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093792/replacing-a-html-div-innertext-tag-using-html-agility-pack?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

creating a textnode does not what it should do in this case:

```
myParentNode.AppendChild(D.CreateTextNode("<script>alert('a');</script>"));
Console.Write(myParentNode.InnerHtml);
```

The result should be something like
&lt;script....

but it is a working script task even if i add it as "TEXT" not as html. This causes kind of a security issue for me because the text would be a input from a anonymous user.